# Can't connect to Postgresql with ssl from IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: postgresql, ssl, intellij-idea, jdbc

I'm trying to reach a Postgresql base via ssl from the builtin database browser in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.

In `datasource properties` I have added the same key and cert pem-files that work fine with psql and pgadmin, but on "Test Connection" I just get

```
[08006] SSL error: No X509TrustManager implementation available
```

---

Updated in response to Andrey's comment:

If I add the local root certificate (which neither psql or pgadmin needed) in the CA file setting, the error changes to

```
[08006] SSL error: No trusting managers found for ECDHE_RSA
```

What am I missing?

Can anyone confirm a working db-connection using:

- IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition 2019.2 or later
- Ssl
- PostgreSQL 12.x or later

Comment: Most likely you are specifying wrong certificate in SSH/SSL settings (or in Advanced tab). Make sure you are specifying the CA file correctly, see
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-8993#focus=streamItem-27-3668746.0-0
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-8993#focus=streamItem-27-3674205.0-0

Try re-creating data source connection from scratch and specify the CA file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I updated my intelliJ to latest version (IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.3 - ultimate). Then it started working.